# php and DB query in javascript without Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**Edit:

I got my problem in this concept,however this may help some other one .thanks all.**




i check one code and it worked properly and i am suprised! because its done without ajax.
the code tested in WAMP and here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1
/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

*{font-size:8pt;}

div#result{

    border:1px solid gray;

    width:50%;

    min-height:50px;

    text-align:right;

    color:#666666;

    font-family:Tahoma;

    padding:3px;

    }

div#result b{color:red;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function GetResult(s){

    var s=document.getElementById('s');

    var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

    resultDiv.innerHTML = '<?php 

    //My PHP Codes

    $conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");

    if(!$conn){echo "Error in DB connection"; }

    mysql_select_db("test");

    mysql_query("set character set utf8");


    $s=sprintf("'+s.value+'");

    $sql = "SELECT *

                FROM `test`";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $row["1"];

        echo "<br />";

        }

    echo "You searched: <b>".$s."</b>";

    ?>';

    }

</script>

</head>


<body>


<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="javascript:GetResult(document.getElementById('s'));return 
false;">

<input type="text" id="s" />

<input type="submit" value="Search!" />

</form>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

the above code retrieve all data from table that named:'test' with DB that named 'test' also.
my query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
```

but the below query dose not work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE `name` LIKE \'%".$s."%\'";
```

why?whats the problem?
Regards

Comment: `$s=sprintf("'+s.value+'");` - wth

Comment: its get the input value from JS.

Comment: Ok, you didn't understand at all that PHP runs on the server and JavaScript on the client. Did you ever have a look at the sourcecode in the browser?

Comment: i knew bro,but i tested it and then posted here,plz test then answer.tnx

Comment: Why would we? We **know** it doesn't work. It worked with your first query because it has the same result no matter what argument is passed to your function - so the value from your PHP code was already present in your JS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand that PHP is a serverside language and requires some form of page reload to run. This is usually done with AJAX or forms.

The way you structured your code indicates that you want the javascript function to return the search results, which is impossible the way you want to do it.

I might aswell write it here. **Your code will never work this way.**

Comment: plz test,then answer! i said that i tested it for retrieve all data,but it dose not work for LIKE query,why?!

Comment: because of the reason i posted. javascript and php just doesnt work the way you think it does.

Comment: so why it works for first query and dose not work for second?

Comment: so plz test it urself my friend :) then comment here ur result

Comment: why would he test it when it's impossible. It worked for the first query because you aren't using any parameters. For the second query you use a parameter from javascript.

Comment: I will not test it, your code is wrong.

Comment: I don't even see how the code as posted would work at all: from what I see, the php portion has no final delimiter, so how is the PHP interpreter deciding when to bail out?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Which column has to be `LIKE \'%".$s."%\'`? Say that column is `colname`. Your query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE colname LIKE \'%".$s."%\'";
```

Looking back over your code you're also doing something /really weird/. That PHP there is being executed /before the javascript ever is sent to the client/. PHP runs serverside, JS runs clientside, so JS can't pass parameters to PHP.

Comment: He used those slashes to escape the single quotes, which he thought he was doing because the PHP was evaluated /after/ the javascript. They are not necessary because obviously that isn't how it works, but that's why ?I edited in the last paragraph of my answer

Comment: tnx,i knew,but i forgot it,with this query it dose not work also!

Comment: I tested it DAN!!! plz attention at the my post!

Comment: Like i said, "That PHP there is being executed /before the javascript ever is sent to the client/. PHP runs serverside, JS runs clientside, so JS can't pass parameters to PHP." YOU CAN'T DO THAT WITHOUT AJAX OR FORMS!

Comment: so why it works for first query and dose not work for second?

Comment: Well you'll need to send the search value from html/javascript (running on my computer) to the php script (running on your server).  The only way to do that is to make a HTTP request, either by posting a form, requesting a URL, or by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only gets executed on the server BEFORE the client machine receives the data. From the client perspective, the portion written using PHP is fixed and will not change using client-side only routines. You must make a new request from the server for the PHP code to be reinterpereted.

It "works" for you "the first time" because the PHP query runs and data is emitted before you receive the page.

Comment: Yes! this is right:"It "works" for you "the first time" because the PHP query runs and data is emitted before you receive the page."  and my question was the reason about first time.tnx